# ZYNQ-ULTRASCALE Warning: verify error at flash adress : 0x0

Tags: embedded, lauterbach, automotive

I got following warning during after-flashing verification.

Code fragment:

```
WAIT 2s
FLASHFILE.LOAD ..\..\..\..\ZZZ_Build_Products\* 0x0 
WAIT 2s
FLASHFILE.LOAD ..\..\..\..\ZZZ_Build_Products\* 0x0  /ComPare
```

During flashing procedure there were no errors or warnings. With such code binary file was needed to be selected manually. Both times were used same the binary file.
Is this is a symptom of flash memory dead maybe?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just a side note: Flashing does commonly not include checks for success. Therefore the verification step is mandatory to be sure. So the error message is a sign of failure. Did you try another unit or another binary?

Comment: Yes, all binaries I tried have same problem - this is why I am assuming flash is dead.

Comment: Also I tried the ones, which were flashing and were verified with success - it also not working now.

Comment: So we can conclude that your unit has a problem.

Comment: as I assummed, unfortunately :/, but thanks for your interesting in topic @thebusybee